# Selecting rows that are within a date range based on a date from another table. (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, which share a key that link the two.  Table A has a date column (of the format MM/DD/YYYY), and table B has a date field of the format (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS).

What I need to do is select all those in table B, that have a key matching table A AND a date field within 30 days of the date field found in table A.

Edit:  Both variables are varchars, here is what I currently have (error from using alias formattedEffective in a join).  I think the below would work, if I could use aliases in that way.

```
select *, 
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(`Eff_date`, '%m/%d/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d') as formattedEffective 
from `customers`
    right join `dispatch` on `customers`.`Member_no` = `dispatch`.`Member_no` 
        AND `dispatch`.`sortdate` > formattedEffective 
        AND `dispatch`.`sortdate` < DATE_ADD(formattedEffective,INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

Comment: Can you share what you've tried? We'd have to see the tables with a little data in order to be able to help you.

Comment: Show what you have tried so far. Little effort on your part will receive the same help from us.

Comment: Updated with the query I have at the moment (don't think I can use 'formattedEffective' the way I intended there.

Comment: If you have stored a date in this format `MM/DD/YYYY` can we also assume that that column is a VARCHAR rather then a DATE or DATETIME or TIMESTAMP

Comment: As someone made that first mistake, would be useful to know what DataType `sortdate` is as well

Comment: Yes indeed, sorry should have mentioned that, but both are varchars

Comment: @Bryant is the table too large to alter the varchar'd column to be a MySQL date/datetime type? You say both are varchar, is this for table B also?

Comment: Both are varchars in both tables, problem is this is a live database that I inherited.  Changing the DB structure would be a last last resort, can't afford any issues with the DB that could result from a data type change (inputs from many places, potential for a 'not perfect' datetime)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the community is asking for is the ability to create a scenario to give a definitive answer to your question (create table statements, sample data, etc..).  The approach below is speculation.

The assumption the query makes is eff_date is a string and sortdate is stored as a MySQL date (i.e., date, datetime, timestamp).

```
select d.*,
       str_to_date(c.eff_date, '%m/%d/%Y') ) as formattedEffective 
  from customer c
  join dispatch d on (   d.member_no = c.member_no
                     and d.sortdate between str_to_date(c.eff_date, '%m/%d/%Y')
                                        and str_to_date(c.eff_date, '%m/%d/%Y')  + interval 30 day );
```

Comment: That did the trick... I have no idea why I didn't think to just use the definition of the alias in the join itself.    Thanks a million!!!

Answer (score 0):

In case [the above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43280502/7278927)
does not work, move the matching range to `where` condition.

```
select d.*,
       str_to_date(c.eff_date, '%m/%d/%Y') ) as formattedEffective 
  from customer c
  join dispatch d on (   d.member_no = c.member_no) 
  where d.sortdate between str_to_date(c.eff_date, '%m/%d/%Y')
                                        and str_to_date(c.eff_date, '%m/%d/%Y')  + interval 30 day );
```